# Is there Number spinner control for ios?

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm looking for a spinner control something similar to this for ios:

http://github.hubspot.com/odometer/docs/welcome/

can't find anything so far, please share if you know any.

[image]

Comment: You can use `UIPickerView` with some customization, Or else you can use `UITableView` too to achieve it.

Comment: https://github.com/timburks/iPadSlotMachine this one is similar like this

Comment: I think you Customization this library :- https://github.com/skywinder/ActionSheetPicker-3.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is one third party library , by which you can do this https://github.com/Rizh/RCounter
https://github.com/naked-apps/NACounter
https://github.com/jonathantribouharet/JTNumberScrollAnimatedView

Answer (score 0):

The nearest thing in iOS, similar to this is UIPickerView. You can create a UIPickerView in the Interface Builder or through code.

Next, make your class conform to `UIPickerViewDataSource` and `UIPickerViewDelegate`.

In your `viewDidLoad:` method, assign the delegate and dataSource of the `UIPickerView` to the respective class.

And finally add the following methods to your class.

```
// The number of columns of data
- (int)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 5;
}

// The number of rows of data
- (int)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return 10;
}

// The data to return for the row and component (column) that's being passed in
- (NSString*)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ul",row];
}
```